# Replace a string in a PDF file using iText for .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, itext

How can I replace a string like #name# in a PDF file using the iText5 for .NET library, I explored it but I could not find any solution.

Comment: You can create a new pdf template and then draw it on the given region.

Comment: Please be aware that pdf is per se not a properly reflowing format. If you are lucky and actually find your placeholder string in the content stream (this might already be difficult, depending in how the pdf was created), replacing it can have many undesired results. if the replacement us longer than the placeholder, it may overwrite following characters or excess characters may be pushed out of visible areas. Additionally, if the font used in the section is a subset, not all characters may be displayed.

Comment: Your question starts from wrong assumptions. Read the intro of this book chapter to understand the flaw in your design (and also to understand why you didn't find any solution): http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is no simple way to do this, because PDF doesn't use a markup language. The way text selection works in a PDF reader like adobe acrobat is essentially via optical character recognition whereby character proximity determines word boundaries.

You can think of a PDF document storing a character definition (ex. 'a'), consisting of styles and co-ordinates. Hence there's no actual representation of a string.

Itextsharp and similar libraries use a builder pattern that give the impression of working with a markup language.

Although I can't offer you a solution, I hope that you may better understand the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case you really need to implement what you described, in spite of all the remarks in the comments and answers,  you might consider doing it like this:

1. Find the placeholder in the page content using the classes in the parser package in concert with a custom RenderListener implementation which returns the position and size of the searched placeholder text.
2. Use a PdfStamper to draw a white rectangle over the placeholder.
3. Use the same PdfStamper to print your replacement over the rectangle.

This procedure has some disadvantages:

- The placeholder is still present in the pdf, it merely is covered.  Thus,  it can be found by text extraction routines,  e.g. copy&paste from a viewer.
- Nothing is reflowed. Thus,  if there is text immediately following the placeholder,  you have to make sure that your replacement string is not too long, and if it is much shorter, you'll see a gap.

If these disadvantages cannot be accepted,  you have to dive right into content stream manipulation which for generic documents is really difficult and full of traps.